# Can't get Eclipse to open

Tags: java, eclipse

Could you please help me anyone.I'm having trouble getting Eclipse to open and run.

I have downloaded the java jdk-6u24-windows-i586, and Eclipse eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32.
I'm new to java and just want to learn to code with it.

Everything is all in the same folder in my C drive. I extracted everything there, but the.exe file does not have the purple Eclipse logo on it. Its looks like a small screen.

When i double click on it, it brings up a small black screen, and says "The Eclipsec executable launcher was unable to locate its companion launcher jar".

There are two .exe file's which is strange, one comes up with that first message and when i click on the other this is the message i get "The Eclipsec executable was unable to locate its companion shared library".

Not sure what i'm doing wrong, as i've downloaded them over and over again, incase something might have gone wrong when i was loading them onto my computer.

Can anyone please help me, as i'm lost as to what to do. I've been looking all over the internet, but can't find any real answer's

Thank you, Bye James

Answer (score 6):

You need to execute `eclipse.exe`, not `eclipsec.exe`. It's two files above, in the explorer.

---

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for answering my question. Its funny because that .exe file is not showing up at all. I have the eclipse.exe but it does not have the purple circle icon of eclipse on it. I downloaded it again, and now when i go to extract it, its telling me that the top header is damaged. Is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers ok to use, rather than the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers? I very new to this and don't know the difference. I think that for some reason the file is always going to be damaged in the dowload for the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Comment: Try a different mirror. Maybe it was a corrupt one. Yesterday after you posted this question I downloaded Helios SR2 for Java EE for Win x64 from the ibiblio mirror and it contained the right files.

Comment: Great, thanks again for your fast response, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

i have this error message when i use extract the files as follows:

- action\select all
- drag and drow the files to an new folder

Somehow information about the folders get lost

when i use "action\extract to..." it works.

Also, remember to right click on eclipse, then choose Security Unblock